# How to start a method from a class to another class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How can I start `getdata()` method to another class. I want to show the output to a `ListView which is in another Java class.

**tab1Background.java**

```
public class tab1Background extends Activity{
ListView lv;

lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
//some code here

    public void getdata() {

       //some code here 
    }
}
```

**tab1report.java** i want to start the getdata() activity to show data in listview

```
public class tab1report extends Fragment {

    //some code here
}
```

Comment: `getData()` activity? which is that activity?

Comment: `((tab1Background)getactivity()).getdata();` in your tab1report fragment.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class tab1report extends Fragment {

    public void startSomething()
    {
        ((tab1Background) getActivity()).getdata();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use callback method.

```
public class tab1report extends Fragment {

    Callback callback;

    public interface Callback {
        void call();
    }

    onAttach(Context context) {
        callback = (Callback) context;
    }

    onStart() {
        // Some code here
        callback.call();
    }

}

public class tab1Background extends Activity implements tab1report.Callback {
    ListView lv;

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    //some code here

    public void getdata() {

        //some code here 
    }

    public void call() {
        getdate();
    }
}
```

This will ensure that the functionality is passed back to the activity.